# Printing a string from a linked list using a function to store and printf to display

Tags: c, linked-list

I appreciate any help I can get. I am currently having an issue printing from a linked list after storing a string. Ideally, I'd be able to display the stored string after handing it through the function and printing it from another function. The code below illustrates my issue and is very similar to my working code. I cannot tell why it won't print. The best I have had so far is (null) and that...for obvious reasons won't cut it. Thanks in advance. I'm still very new to coding in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct class{
  char *prefix_name; // will store something like "MAC 544"
  int  cred_hours;
  int  crn_number;
};
struct student{
  int id;
  char f_name[50];
  char l_name[50];
  struct class c_one;
};

char stu_test(struct student *info){
  char x;
  x = "MAC 344";
  return x;
}

int main() {
  struct student info[100];

  info[0].c_one.prefix_name=stu_test(info);

  printf("%s\n", info[0].c_one.prefix_name);


  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the switch that I will use.....hopefully

```
char *crnName(int crn){
  char *name;
  switch (crn) {
    case 4587:
      name="MAT 236";
    break;
    case 4599:
      name="COP 220";
    break;
    case 8997:
      name="GOL 124";
    break;
    case 9696:
      name="COP 100";
    break;
    case 1232:
      name="MAC 531";
    break;
    case 9856:
      name="STA 100";
    break;
    case 8520:
      name="TNV 400";
    break;
    case 8977:
      name="CMP 100";
    break;
  }
  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at `stu_test()` function:

```
char stu_test(struct student *info){
  char x;
  x = "MAC 344";
  return x;
}
```

`"MAC 344"` is a string literal and you are assigning it to `x` which is of type `char`. Compiler must be giving warning message for this. I am using `gcc` compiler and getting warning message:

```
prg.c:19:5: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [8]' [-Wint-conversion]
  x = "MAC 344";
```

You should change the type of `x` and return type of `stu_test()` function to `char *`:

```
char * stu_test(struct student *info){
  char * x;
  x = "MAC 344";
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea for a function to return an automatic variable... the value of which goes out of scope upon return.

Comment: @TonyB its not returning the value. It is returning the pointer to a string literal which is valid because string literals have static storage duration.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, "MAC 344" is static, and you are therefore correct...

Comment: While the test code is now fixed, thank you by the way, I'm still having an issue on calling it in my main code. I will end up having the code print in through an invoice function. So is there something I need to do to fix that? All I get is a (null) value.
Also, I'm using "x" as a way to assign the prefix to that location in the array, but x has the potential of being other names, to account for this I used the CRN which is a unique identifier to decide what the name of x will be by running it through a switch.

Comment: @Rando Are you sure that the value of `crn` matching to one of the `case` of `switch` statement? Add a `default` case in your `switch` and assign some dummy string to `name` in it, like `name="DUMMY"` and then check your code. If still problem persist, I would suggest you to add the actual code in the question.

Comment: @H.S After going back and looking you were right and it works. Thank you very much. As far as the default case, I have a loop prior to this statement that restricts the user input to only those numbers. Should I still include a default?

Comment: @Rando Though, the `default` case is not necessary, as a good programming practice it is good to add `default` case because if no choices were made then statement under `default` case gets executed. In your case even if you have some code to validate the `crn` value before calling `crnName()` function but still, i think, `default` case should be there to cover some corner cases like assume your set of valid `crn` value increases and you missed adding case for one them (think about a case where someone else is modifying your code). Feel free to accept this answer if you found it useful.